# How to get Document Outline in VS 2013 like in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, styles, document, outline

In VS 2010 Document Outline window looked very nice. But in VS 2013 it looks very bad! It is hard to recognize where control name is, where control type is. Icons, letters - all have black color.

How to get Document Outline in VS 2013 like in VS2010?

Beauty outline VS 2010

[image: Beauty outline VS 2010]

Terrible outline VS 2013

[image: Terrible outline VS 2013]

Comment: try changing the theme of visual studio

Comment: @utility where does it change?

Comment: try this theme editor and let me know :https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9e08e5d3-6eb4-4e73-a045-6ea2a5cbdabe

Comment: @utility this editor just change color of VS itself. It doesn't change icons, fonts, colors in Document Outline Window. Unfortunately useless.

Comment: ohh kk will have detailed study on issue and ll post